# Is it possible to obtain a value for errors in measured quantities from R squared regression value?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, regression, descriptive-statistics, mean-square-error

I conducted an experiment which it was not possible to repeat, however it gave me a series of 15 points $(x_i,y_i)$. I applied a linear regression to this data and obtained a high R squared value of $R^2=0.9991$

Alhtough I was not able to repeat my measurements, I know that they were subject to some random error and I was wondering if it is possible to work backwards from the R squared value to find an estimate for the error in each data point.

Unfortunately I am not very experienced when it comes to statistics, and what I have read about this so far has been very confusing.

Comment: Normally the residuals, i.e. observed $y$-values minus fitted $y$-values, are taken to be estimates of the errors. Maybe I could say more if I saw the data.

Comment: Just from the $R^2$, you would not be able to get the residuals for each observation.The $R^2$ is 1 - (sum of squared residuals)/(total sum of squares). You would, however, be able to backtrace to find the sum of squared residuals (SSR)

Comment: @Zslice thank you for your comment. I am slightly confused as I read that r squared is the variation explained by the model/total variation. However a perfect linear model does not assume/predict any variation, so how is this variation 'explained'?

Comment: @21joanna12 in a perfect linear model, the prediction is equal to the actual value of the dependent variable for all observations. If you look at the formulas for ESS (explained sum of squares) and TSS (total sum of squares), you will find that ESS = TSS in a perfect linear model, resulting in an r squared that equals 1

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your simple linear regression model is 
$$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + e_i,$$
where $e_i$ are iid $Norm(0, \sigma_e).$ Also, I suppose that you have $n$ data pairs 
$(x_i, Y_i),$ which you use to find estimates $\hat \beta_0$ of $\beta_0.\,$
$\hat \beta_1\,$ of $\beta_1,$ and $s_e^2$ of $\sigma_e^2.$
Then the regression line passes through the $n$ points $(x_i, \hat Y_i),$ where
$\hat Y_i = \hat \beta_0 + \hat \beta_1 x_i.$

A 95% confidence interval for a fitted value $\hat Y_i$ corresponding to $x_i$
is of the form
$$\hat Y_i \pm t^*s_e\sqrt{\frac{1}{n} + \frac{(x_i - \bar x)^2}{(n-1)s_x^2}},$$
where $\bar x$ and $s_x^2$ are the sample mean and variance, respectively, of
the $x_i,\,$ $t^*$ cuts area .025 from the upper tail of Student's t distribution with $n-2$ degrees of freedom, and $s_e$ is the above mentioned estimate of $\sigma_e^2$ of the
regression model. This estimate can be found as
$$s_e^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i - \hat Y_i)^2}{n-2} = 
\frac{n-1}{n-2}s_Y^2(1 - r^2).$$

If you did the regression procedure using statistical software, then $s_e$ or
$s_e^2$ may have been part of the regression printout. In the right-hand
expression above, $s_Y^2$ is the sample variance of the $Y_i$
and $r^2$ (possibly `R-sq` or '$R^2$' in the regression
printout) is the square of the correlation $r$ between the $x_i$ and $Y_i.$
[If you use that expression for computation, you must not round anything off
before you get the result $s_e^2.$]

So you can use the value $R^2$ you mentioned to get a confidence interval
for your predicted points, provided you have the original data available
so that the other quantities in the formula can be computed also.

Notice that errors become larger as the  $x_i$s get farther from their
average $\bar x.$ This is because the regression line must pass through
the point $(\bar x, \bar Y),$ and any error in estimating the slope $\beta_1$
of the regression line is exaggerated as one moves away from this 'center
of the data cloud'.

*Notes:* (1) The formula for the *confidence* interval (CI) above is fine if you are
talking about errors in the $\hat Y_i$s from the original data. If you
are trying to predict the value $Y_{n+1}$ corresponding to an *additional* $x_{n+1}$, not used in finding the regression line, then the *prediction* interval (PI) is somewhat longer:
$$\hat Y_{n+1} \pm t^*s_e\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{(x_{n+1} - \bar x)^2}{(n-1)s_x^2}}.$$

(2) Almost all of the formulas I have given here are standard ones found in
most elementary statistics texts, except I have tried to avoid any
unnecessary terminology and symbols. I am not surprised that you had difficulty
finding just what you needed in your own browsing. I hope it helps to have
just the formulas and symbols you actually need for your task. If you need
further assistance, please edit into your question separate lists your 15 x-values and 15 Y-values, each along its own row, with values separated by commas. Then leave me a Comment, and I will try to answer within a day or two.